# scrlayer-scrpage: Use tikz picture as part of the header in one-sided document

Tags: tikz-pgf, koma-script, scrlayer-scrpage

I would like to have a tikz picture recurring on every page of a certain pagestyle except for the page with the chapter title. When compiling the MWE, I get the picture only on the page with the chapter title but nowhere else. I would also like to omit the section title from the first page of the chapter.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside,headsepline=true,chapterprefix=false,headings=optiontohead,toc=indentunnumbered, usegeometry]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}

    
%%%---header/footer
\usepackage[
automark,
autooneside=false,% <- needed if you want to use \leftmark and \rightmark in a onesided document
headsepline
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newpairofpagestyles{MyIntro}{%
    \clearpairofpagestyles%
    \ohead*{\ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightbotmark}{}{\rightbotmark}}{%
            \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
                \node[rectangle, minimum width=0.12\paperheight, minimum height=1.3cm, fill=gray!50, text=white, font=\fontsize{14}{14}\bfseries, xshift=-.55cm,yshift=-5cm,rotate=90] at (current page.north east){\makebox[0pt][c]{\hspace{0cm} Introduction}};
            \end{tikzpicture}
    }
    \ofoot*{\pagemark}
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

    \thispagestyle{empty}
    \tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}

\pagestyle{MyIntro}

\section{The First Section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{The Second Section}

\lipsum[4-12]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you are adding the `tikzpicture` to the *selection* of the page style. To make it a part of the page style either add it using `\ohead` etc. or define a new layer and add this new layer to the page style. Additionally, I would not recommend to add any mark (but `\pagemark`) to the plain style, because the plain style it mentioned to be used for pages without running head. So I get, e.g.:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside,headsepline=true,chapterprefix=false,headings=optiontohead,toc=indentunnumbered, usegeometry]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
    
%%%---header/footer
\usepackage[
automark,
autooneside=false,% <- needed if you want to use \leftmark and \rightmark in a onesided document
headsepline
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\newpairofpagestyles{MyIntro}{%
  \clearpairofpagestyles
  \ohead{%
    \Ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightbotmark}{}{\rightbotmark}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[rectangle, minimum width=0.12\paperheight, minimum height=1.3cm,
      fill=gray!50, text=white, font=\fontsize{14}{14}\bfseries,
      xshift=-.55cm,yshift=-5cm,rotate=90] at (current page.north
      east){\makebox[0pt][c]{\hspace{0cm} Introduction }};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }%
  \ofoot*{\pagemark}%
}

\pagestyle{MyIntro}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagestyle{MyIntro}


\section{The First Section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{The Second Section}

\lipsum[4-12]

\end{document}
```

[image: three pages with chapter thumbs at second and third]

BTW: Options `oneside` and `chapterprefix=false` are defaults with `scrreprt`. Option `usegeometry` make sense only if you would load package `geometry`.

An alternative suggestion would be, to use the LaTeX mark mechanism also for the text of the chapter thumb, e.g., using the new commands documented in `ltmarks-doc.pdf` (available in every LaTeX distribution, that provides these commands):

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside,headsepline=true,chapterprefix=false,headings=optiontohead,toc=indentunnumbered, usegeometry]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage{tikz}
    
%%%---header/footer
\usepackage[
automark,
autooneside=false,% <- needed if you want to use \leftmark and \rightmark in a onesided document
headsepline
]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\NewMarkClass{chaptername}

\newpairofpagestyles{MyIntro}{%
  \clearpairofpagestyles
  \ohead{%
    \Ifstr{\leftmark}{\rightbotmark}{}{\rightbotmark}%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
      \node[rectangle, minimum width=0.12\paperheight, minimum height=1.3cm,
      fill=gray!50, text=white, font=\fontsize{14}{14}\bfseries,
      xshift=-.55cm,yshift=-5cm,rotate=90] at (current page.north
      east){\FirstMark{chaptername}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  }%
  \ofoot*{\pagemark}%
}

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xapptocmd{\chaptermark}{\InsertMark{chaptername}{#1}}{}{}

\pagestyle{MyIntro}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Introduction}
\pagestyle{MyIntro}


\section{The First Section}
\lipsum[1-3]

\section{The Second Section}

\lipsum[4-12]

\end{document}
```

BTW: Currently is makes no sense to define a new pair of page styles instead of using the predefined pair `scrheadings` and `plain.scrheadings`. However, maybe in your real document, there is a sense. So I've not changed this.

Comment: Thank you for all the explanations! I used the first solution, which works perfectly. the second one gives me the error undefined command: \FirstMark, could this be because I compile the real document with LuaLatex?

Comment: @C.Carl Your LaTeX is outdated. The extended mark mechanism is available since June 2022. See [`ltnews35.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltnews35.pdf) and [`ltmarks-doc.pdf`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/base/ltmarks-doc.pdf). This is independent from using PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX.